# Android studio Gradle sync failed CreateProcess error=5

Tags: java, android, gradle

I updated my android studio from an old version to 2.2.0-beta2, and i get this Gradle sync failed CreateProcess error=5.

any ideas how I fix this?

Comment: Make a new project?

Comment: tried didnt work still

Comment: Post the code in build.gradle to your question

Comment: found the solution needed to change the jdk i was using

Comment: Way to go! You can now add your answer how you fixed it just in case someone else run into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution needed to change the jdk i was using.